# How to do this REGEX in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have a youtube video embed code that looks like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGdfNb15h9o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to add the following (it gets rid of related video suggestions):

```
?rel=0
```

to the end of each url in the embed code. So in the above example, the final code should look like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGdfNb15h9o?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The embed code is stored in a variable called `$embed_code`. How can I transform the embed code to hav the `?rel=0` applied to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything else is staying constant you can use str_replace instead which will be faster.

```
    <?php
$iframe = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGdfNb15h9o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$pattern = '" frameborder="0"';
$replace = '?rel=0" frameborder="0"';

$iframe = str_replace($pattern,$replace, $iframe);

echo $iframe;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more more information or source code, I don't think you need regex. Why not do:

```
$embed_code.= "?rel=0";
```

before you output your HTML?

Comment: Maybe the iframe-code is copy-pasted from somewhere else by a user? The question is straightforward imho

Comment: @Adam Field the variable contains the entire iframe embed code not just the url. That's how they are stored in the database I am working with.

Comment: IMO, OP means `$embed_code` holds from `<iframe>` to `</iframe>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:
`preg_replace('~src=('|")(http://www.youtube\.com.+?)\1~',"src='\2?rel=0'",$input);`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another different answer :

```
$result = preg_replace('/(src\s*=([\'"]).*?(?=\2))/s', '$1?rel=0', $subject);
```

I guess either of the above regexes would work. It's just a matter of preference :)

**Explanation :**

```
"
(             # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   src           # Match the characters “src” literally
   \s            # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *             # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   =             # Match the character “=” literally
   (             # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      ['\"]          # Match a single character present in the list “'\"”
   )
   .             # Match any single character
      *?            # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   (?=           # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
      \2            # Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 2
   )
)
"
```

Comment: Did you hand-write the explanation, or do you have a tool for it?

Comment: @Evert Of course not, although I could I am not crazy :D. There are plenty of tools, most notably regexbuddy and expresso.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
$str = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGdfNb15h9o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$pattern = '/(http:\/\/www.youtube.com[^\"]*)/';
$str = preg_replace($pattern,"$1?rel=0",$str);
echo $str;
```